# Post Closed - Primarily Opinion Based - But it does not appear to be opinion based to me

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, allowed-topics

Post: [Shared data between multiple devices / Operating systems](https://superuser.com/questions/1353869/shared-data-between-multiple-devices-operating-systems)

I'm not asking for the best one, I'm not asking whether people like a solution or not. I'm asking "What solutions exist to address this problem?"

Whether or not something is a solution is not opinion based -- either it objectively functions as a solution or it doesn't.

It's like asking "What video decoding library can I use for a Python program?" There might be a dozen out there, and determining which is best might be opinion based (and it might not be, given a specific enough requirement set) but identifying the solutions has nothing to do with opinions.

"I have need X, I have constraints Y, I have tried Z, and I am looking for a good solution." is the form of any good question on this site.

I'd like for this thread to be re-opened please.

---

In the comments here, "burgi" and "fixer1234" have suggested my question is actually "too broad" rather than "opinion based", although it remains closed for being opinion based despite not being so.

It is also not too broad, by the standards of other posts on this site:

[How to run virtual machines on top of Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/300730/how-to-run-virtual-machines-on-top-of-windows-7) -- there must be a dozen ways to run virtual machines on top of windows 7.

[How to recover data from deleted dynamic disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1353718/how-to-recover-data-from-deleted-dynamic-disk) -- There must be literally a hundred ways to recover data from a deleted disk.

[How to block all traffic on Win10 except for 2 programs](https://superuser.com/questions/1354012/how-to-block-all-traffic-on-win10-except-for-2-programs) -- There are a number of ways of ways to block traffic on windows 10.

[Possible in bash? Turning command expansion into arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/1353966/possible-in-bash-turning-command-expansion-into-arguments) -- The first answer provides four or five answers to the question, and there are more out there.

[How to diagnose if lubuntu system freezes due to low memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1353960/how-to-diagnose-if-lubuntu-system-freezes-due-to-low-memory) -- The first answer lists three solutions, and there are undoubtedly more out there in the linux ecosystem.

[How do I set a random background image in LightDM GTK Greeter (Gentoo)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1353933/how-do-i-set-a-random-background-image-in-lightdm-gtk-greeter-gentoo) -- There must be a dozen ways to accomplish this task.

[How do I make a machine "blank screen" for a period of time (as a penalty) if certain noise levels are reached?](https://superuser.com/questions/545329/how-do-i-make-a-machine-blank-screen-for-a-period-of-time-as-a-penalty-if-ce) -- One of the most popular questions on the site. There are countless possible solutions to this problem.

[Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) -- Another popular question that has multiple possible answers.

I spent ten minutes looking for examples.

---

I have a question. It is about computer software, which is one of the three topics allowed here. It has an objectively right answer -- if software exists to fix my problem, it can be identified, tested, and I can accept the answer that suggested working software.

Despite the foregoing, it has been closed by a single moderator. It may have been closed for being opinion based, even though it's not opinion based. Then in this thread I'm told it is closed because there are too many viable answers, even though there are plenty of examples (including highly regarded questions) which have many potential answers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82709/discussion-on-question-by-joshuad-post-closed-primarily-opinion-based-but-it).

Answer (score 5):

Well - broadness isn't just for solutions, it is for *problems*.

Incidentally I hate it when folks go "What about all these other questions" - it just is kind of a "If my question gets closed all the other questions that seem too broad to me get closed".

Feel free to vote to close when you have enough reputation, but throwing a huge list of questions you think should be closed is unhelpful.

Its too broad because you're trying to solve multiple problems across multiple platforms. Its ok to have more than one way to skin a cat. Its not ok if you are looking for ways to skin felines, chop onions and solder paper together, all at once.

Comment: I don't think those questions should be closed...

Comment: And the problem being cross-platform is the core of the problem. It is the heart of it.